# Is there an easy or built-in way to say "when I do nothing" in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

So I have been writing some Cucumber tests.

For example, I have test:

```
Given I have a category page "Art"
When I create a subcategory page "Painting"
Then the subcategory page "Painting" should be created
```

The test has been written, and it's passing.

Now to make sure my test is working as expected, I want to try

```
Given I have a category page "Art"
When I do nothing
Then the subcategory page "Painting" should be created
```

Now, the test should fail.

Is there some easy, built-in Cucumber way to express "I do nothing" without
my having to define this step explicitly, which would be just

```
When(/^I do nothing$/) do
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, (note: I did not say unfortunately) that seems to be the only way. Because having that empty step definition establishes/proves that you are doing nothing there.